# Screen flickering since day 1 with Intel

Tags: graphics, intel

**Since first time freya was released** I had this screen flicker when moving, resizing windows. I hope that it will be fixed in some time so i sticked with luna. After months nothing was fixed still. I found some outdated fix on interent which didnt work, or worked for one part. Why is this not fixed for Intel chips?

Comment: What is your Intel Chip and GPU.

Comment: Did you reported this as a bug at Launchpad?